# Console stopping the rest of the script from running

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I have 2 Forms and a Console, the console is initiated through a function in the second form called Start()

```cs
    public void Start()
        {
            Console.Title = "RPG";
            strength.Visible = true;
            dexterity.Visible = true;
            constitution.Visible = true;
            intelligence.Visible = true;
            wisdom.Visible = true;
            charisma.Visible = true;
            Console.Clear();
            string race;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please press 'Enter' to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("This is a world divided by Race, War and Gods...");
            Console.WriteLine("Since the days of old, conflict was common and War was eternal");
            Console.WriteLine("Please press 'Enter' to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What race do you wish to be?");
            Console.WriteLine("_____________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("(1) Human \n(2) Elf \n(3) Dwarf");
            Console.WriteLine("_____________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("(4) Faun \n(5) Orc \n(6) Aswang \n");
            Console.Write("Choice: ");
            race = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            switch (race)
            {
                case "1":
                case "human":
                    Console.WriteLine("\nHumans are native to the rolling hills of Interit");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please press 'Enter' to continue.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    First();
                    break;

                case "2":
                case "elf":
                    Console.WriteLine("\nElves are native to the forests of Abrines");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please press 'Enter' to continue.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    First();
                    break;

                case "3":
                case "dwarf":
                    Console.WriteLine("\nDwarves are native to the rocky regions of Dunfall");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please press 'Enter' to continue.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    First();
                    break;

                case "4":
                case "faun":
                    Console.WriteLine("\nFaun serve in the Ashlands of Ethana");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please press 'Enter' to continue.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    First();
                    break;

                case "5":
                case "orc":
                    Console.WriteLine("\nOrcs serve in the country of Ocrain");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please press 'Enter' to continue.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    First();
                    break;

                case "6":
                case "aswang":
                    Console.WriteLine("\nAswang serve in the Weytane Woodlands");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please press 'Enter' to continue.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    First();
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid option!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please press 'Enter' to continue.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Start();
                    break; 
            }
```

This function is called from the first form upon clicking a proceed button, then the first forms visibility is set to false. The Main() function looks like this and is in the same script as the Start() function.

```cs
public void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form2.Hide();
            Application.Run(form1);
        }
```

My problem is that once Start() is called, the form cant be closed, moved, minimized, maximized etc. and I have figured out that it's because of the console, however I can't find anything online on how to run the console separately so that it doesn't interfere with the form. Any ideas?

Edit: I should add that it starts as a console application, which makes the console appear upon run.

Comment: That sounds very unusual - although the fact that you're talking about "other console commands down here with pauses" sounds relevant. Does the `Start()` method ever actually *complete*? It would be really useful if you could provide a [mcve] rather than just snippets.

Comment: Let me edit it and include the full code.. but it doesn't actually finish now that you mention it

Comment: What do you mean `a Console`? There's only one console per console application. The code you posted just changes the title and writes a string, it doesn't wait for anything - unless there's a `Console.Read` or `Console.ReadKey` in the omitted code.

Comment: @yoshirouuu don't post all the code, post a *minimal* example that reproduces the problem. Writing to the Windows console doesn't block

Comment: The code isn't very long so I don't think it should be a problem, I should also add that it starts as a console application

Comment: `Console.ReadLine();` will block until you press enter in the console. Now though, my question is: if you're building a forms application, why do you need a console to interact with the user? The whole point of a forms application is that you interact with the user via the graphical interface provided by the form. There's no logical reason to use the console here for anything (except perhaps debugging) as far as I can see. Why didn't you implement this question sequence within a form (or forms / dialogs)?

Comment: Or, if you want a purely console-based experience on purpose, then just create a simple console app without any of the forms stuff in it. Mixing the two environments together really does **not** make sense and will also be a weird and potentially confusing experience for users (even if you get it working as you want).

Comment: @ADyson It's for the sake of older console based text RPG's... I could have done it that way but I didn't want to. It also relates to my question of whether I'm able to make a class specifically for the console then as to not let it interfere with the form?

Comment: "It's for the sake of older console based text RPG's"...this doesn't really explain your logic. If you want a console app, then use a plain console app.

Comment: @ADyson As right as you are, it's a bit of fun and I want to get them to interact together

Comment: Well you're not using either of them as they're designed to be used, and I'd be very surprised if you could get it to work in a sensible way. I'm sure you could trigger a console as a separate process, but if you then wanted to pass the data back to the forms app when it's finished that might be tricky (unless you write to a shared data source of some kind).

Comment: @ADyson If I wanted to have a console text rpg with just the console, I would have just used batch code. But I feel like doing it like this puts a fun spin on it instead of just using the console. I know it's possible because I've seen it countless times, just not for making a text rpg. Knowing full well it's possible, getting it to work is part of the fun.

Comment: Unless you're allocating a console somewhere, this is never going to work. `stdout` doesn't go anywhere useful in a WinForms app.

Comment: @3Dave How would I do that then? Can I make a script specifically for the console?

Comment: I would expect it to be fine if you just span up a separate thread for all the console aspects. But it *is* a very odd thing to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've never tried anything to do with threading, so how would I do that? And if it's odd then so be it

Comment: There are *hundreds* of tutorials about threading. It's not really the right topic for a Stack Overflow comment thread. I suggest you do some research, and ask a new specific question if you run into problems.

Comment: @JonSkeet Got it, I'll do some research :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some of the comments on your question, there is mention that you're not supposed to mix console interaction and windows forms (or other GUI) interaction in the same application.  There is a reason for that that is important to understand.

Every windows program has a loop where it receives input events and sends them to be processed.  In Windows Forms applications, this is kind of obvious because you write handlers to respond to input events.  In Console Applications, the event loop is still there but it is hidden from you. When you are in Console Read, the console collects input events to assemble a string and returns it to you when it responds to the "Enter" input events.  (Note that modal forms take over the event loop in a similar way to the console).

To get a console-type application that also has responsive forms, you might want to create your own "Console" class that is a Windows Form with a display area and an input area.  This way you can have the regular Windows event loop handle everything.  You will have to handle input in a little more sophisticated way: instead of just waiting on a Console.Read at a certain point in your program, you will have to keep
track of what kind of input you are expecting when the use hits Enter (or a submit button, or whatever).

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense! Thanks for explaining :)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I worked with forms, so take this with a grain of salt....

You mention that you hide Form1. If Form1 is modal, it will block Form2 from accepting input. To experiment, don't hide Form1 and see if closing it solves the problem. If yes, then change modal property to false.

Comment: It's actually something to do with the console commands, I know because as soon as I took that chunk of code out, everything worked, which means it's likely to do with the Console.ReadLine() command which waits for user input.

Comment: so if you comment out `race = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();`, it does what you expect?

Comment: And all the other Console.ReadLines()s, yes

Comment: I'd be curious to know what happens if you remove .ToLower(). If I can find time this weekend I'll try myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run both/all in differend Tasks like so

```
    class Settings
    {
        public bool ShowConsole { get; set; }
        public bool ShutDown { get; set; }
        // Other staff
    }

    static Settings settings = new Settings();

    public static void Main()
    {
        var forms = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // After Btn Click 
            settings.ShowConsole = true;

            // Or 
            settings.ShutDown = true;
        });
        var console = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!settings.ShutDown) 
            {
                if (settings.ShowConsole)
                {
                    // Show
                    settings.ShowConsole = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Hide
                }
            }
        });
        Task.WaitAll(forms, console);
    }
```

Comment: This looks a little complicated to me, how would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Either asyncronious tasks or in separated projects. I do not see else how you cann run all together, case you did it and they did not block themself you can than resize the console to 0x0

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to go about this... I'll keep looking!

Comment: Great suggestion! Hopefully OP will revisit this after more experience.